# Convert Transparent PNG to JPG with Non-Black Background Color

Tags: c#, .net, image-conversion, alpha-transparency

I'm using System.Drawing.Image in .Net to do a simple conversion from png to jpeg. 
I'm basically just using these two lines of code:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(filename);
img.Save(newFilename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

it works fine except for when the png files contain transparency due to the alpha channel. In which case the converted jpeg has a black background. Is there any way to make the background white instead?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
// Assumes myImage is the PNG you are converting
using (var b = new Bitmap(myImage.Width, myImage.Height)) {
    b.SetResolution(myImage.HorizontalResolution, myImage.VerticalResolution);

    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(b)) {
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        g.DrawImageUnscaled(myImage, 0, 0);
    }

    // Now save b as a JPEG like you normally would
}
```

Comment: for anyone reading about this question in the future, I also found it helpful to set the resolution of the bitmap object before declaring the graphics object: b.SetResolution (myImage.HorizontalResolution, myImage.VerticalResolution); This will avoid some scaling issues during the conversion

Comment: How do I use the opposite, i.e. I want to move all my JPG images to PNG and all the whites should be replaced with transparent.

Comment: @Shimmy: `Bitmap.SetTransparencyKey(Color.White)`. The saving part is easy, though - the image can be loaded in exactly the same way, and just change `ImageFormat.Jpeg` to `ImageFormat.Png`.

Comment: OMG I used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382683/convert-transparent-png-in-color-to-single-color/3382770#3382770) long solution. Anyway the function name is `Bitmap.MakeTransparent`. Thank you so much.

Comment: @DaveS -- Setting the resolution is a good suggestion -- feel free to edit the answer.