# I am having a object in powershell and want to save it in new directory after renaming it

Tags: powershell

Here `$pngImage` is a PNG file object and I want to save it at `$folderPath`, but only new image is getting created with `$pngfile` name but content is not same as `$pngImage`.

```psh
$folderPath = $outputfolder + '\' + $capfile.FullName.Split('\')[3] + '\' +
              $capfile.FullName.Split('\')[4] + '\'+$capfile.FullName.Split('\')[6]

if (!(Test-Path $folderPath))
{
  Write-Host "Creating folder:" $folderPath
  New-Item $folderPath -Type Directory
}   

$pngImage = Get-Image -capFile $capfile -folderLoc $folderPath
$pngfile = $capfile.BaseName+".png"
New-Item -Path $folderPath -name $pngfile -ItemType "file" -Value $pngImage. -force
```

Comment: Get-Image is a custom function? Can you use solutions mentioned [already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863021/convert-all-images-to-jpg)

Comment: yes it is returning only png object and deleteing source folder after returing the object

Comment: can you use solutions mentioned [already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863021/convert-all-images-to-jpg) or does the file cease to exist before you go to save?

Comment: How *exactly* is the content different? Also, please show the implementation of `Get-Image`.