# Convert gif to jpg with transparent background

Tags: powershell, image-conversion

Before everyone would link [Convert all images to jpg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863021/convert-all-images-to-jpg) I must say I am using solution from this thread already.

I am converting huge amount of static gif files to jpg. However some of them have transparent background and there I am getting black background which is not acceptable.

I was trying to use `MakeTransparent()` but I don't get how to use it or it doesn't work.

```
# first try
$image.MakeTransparent("white")

# second try
$col = "#FFFFFF"
$image.MakeTransparent([System.Drawing.ColorTranslator]::FromHtml($col))
```

Both run in powershell without errors but both generate black background.

I found also `Bitmap.Clear(Color.White)` and `Bitmap.SetTransparencyKey(Color.White)` but when I trying run code I receive an error

> Method invocation failed because [System.Drawing.Bitmap] does not contain a method named 'Clear'.

Same for `SetTransparenctKey`.

Is there any other simple function to make transparent background white?

Answer (score 3):

JPG can’t support transparent background. It uses RGB color space. Use another format like PNG.

Comment: That's why I want make background white and using PNG would by easiest but I **have to** make jpegs.