# c#: reduced image quality when saving JPEG at 100% quality

Tags: image, save, jpeg

I'm just loading JPEG image and saving it without any manipulation with it. But image quality noticeably reducing.

Here is the code:

```
Bitmap imgOutput = new Bitmap(@"D:\image.jpg");
Graphics outputGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(imgOutput);      

EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(3);
myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);
myEncoderParameters.Param[1] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.ScanMethod, (int)EncoderValue.ScanMethodInterlaced);
myEncoderParameters.Param[2] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.RenderMethod, (int)EncoderValue.RenderProgressive);

ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
ImageCodecInfo ici = null;
foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
{
    if (codec.MimeType == "image/jpeg")
        ici = codec;
}

imgOutput.Save(@"D:\result.jpg", ici, myEncoderParameters);
```

And what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KLHV.jpg zoom: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zm8t9.jpg

Is there another image quality settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JPEG, being a lossy format introduces loss on every save. It is also particularly bad at compressing sharp edges. According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882583.aspx), you're setting the image quality correctly. You can play with the other settings if you want to try and optimize the image quality, as I don't know how you came up with the ScanMethod and RenderMethod. However, the best way in my opinion is to use a lossless format (PNG, TIFF, etc).

**Update**

It appears  that this is due to the bad GDI+ JPEG encoder. More on it on [the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/ed3e9f13-2290-40c7-9284-d280430ac6cb). The conclusion is - use a third party imaging library, there are plenty free ones out there.

Comment: Yes, PNG saves great. But despite the fact that JPEG is lossy format, when I open image in Photoshop and then save it as JPEG, result image is flawless (and even with less file size). This means that JPEG format allow saving images more correct. And I would like to know how)

Comment: @user1032559 It appears to be GDI+ that is bad. See update and link.

Comment: I viewed the source code of this tool - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9727/Image-Processing-Lab-in-C It saves images with standart methods and works well. The one difference is that they don't use EncoderParameters. But when I save  image without these parameters, the overall quality of JPEG is very low.

Comment: If you want the best quality you can get - look for ImageMagick or another free image processing library. There is also a JPEG encoder in C# somewhere on CodePlex. I share your experience that when you leave out EncoderParameters, the quality is OK, but I'm not sure why and if that's always going to be the case.