# C++/CLI: ColorMatrix for applying an Alpha Threshold

Tags: image-processing, c++-cli, alpha, colormatrix, mouse-picking

Would anyone know how to specify a ColorMatrix (Specifically a System::Drawing::Imaging::ColorMatrix in C++/CLI) to set an alpha threshold? For example if I were to use 10 (10/255) as my threshold then any pixel with an RGBA Alpha of 10 or less would have 0.0f Alpha and every pixel above would get 1.0f.

I'm trying to implement ColorID picking in a 2D scene editor as I'm sick of using my current unwieldy method of reversing my drawing transformations to determine which pixel of a given bitmap the mouse is pointing at. So what I want to do instead is do a ColorID rendering pass like in OpenGL as described here http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL_Selection_Using_Unique_Color_IDs However I can't just compare the locations of bitmaps onscreen as most of them include tons of white-space that I don't want being picked up by mouse picking which leaves me with color-picking.

For now my ColorMatrix looks like

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
R G B 0 1
```

following Hans' answer to [GDI+: Set all pixels to given color while retaining existing alpha value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510013/gdi-set-all-pixels-to-given-color-while-retaining-existing-alpha-value) but I'd like it to also apply a threshold to the Alpha component (provided that's even possible using a ColorMatrix)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for the [`ImageAttributes.SetThreshold`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6464csbe) method.

Comment: Well not particularly, see this only seems to affect the RGB values, whereas I want the threshold to be applied only to Alpha values with the colors just being altogether replaced with a single solid color. I also would prefer it to be in the form of a ColorMatrix rather than an API-provided function, but that relies on a ColorMatrix even being capable of doing Threshold operations.

Comment: @Stony: Well, the operation you're asking for is non-linear, so a matrix multiply isn't going to cut it.  A matrix multiply followed by clipping just might, but I wasn't able to tell whether there's a clipping step involved with the color transform.

Comment: Yeah I had a feeling that was the case, like I said ImageAttributes.SetThreshold would do the trick if it could be used for Alpha but I guess I'm stuck in that regard. Maybe I'll just loop through each pixel in a texture myself before drawing and set the Alpha Threshold manually, then use the ColorMatrix to set the bitmap's flat color like I already do. It'll be ugly and slow but it should do the trick